# Помогите составить regexp выражение для htaccess и nginx

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, nginx

Ссылка вида https://www.site.com/School/12set/Pages/default.aspx
Нужно перейти на https://12set.site.com/

Пока дошел только до:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} Schools/([^.]+)\.aspx [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.site.com [R=302,L]
```

Если есть кто может помочь с написанием конфига напрямую для nginx, буду премного благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Сделал через location

```
location ^/Schools/(.+)/Pages/default.aspx$
```